# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65936, result=0, data=null}

Tags: java, android, android-camera, firebase-storage

Please help me solve this issue. When I select image to be uploaded, the app crashes. It been days now and i am still stack with this issue.

Log.d point at

uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);

storageReference2nd.putFile(uri)

Your help is really needed. Thanks

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Calling a method for after picking image from gallery or camera

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)


        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + data);

            //Image is picked from gallery, get uri of the image
            image_uri = data.getData();

            uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);

        }

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
        //Image is picked from camera, get uri of the image

        uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void uploadProfileCoverPhoto(Uri uri) {
    //Show progress Bar
    LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Path and the name of image to be stored in firebase storage
    String filePathAndName = storagePath + "" + profileOrCoverPhoto + "_" + user.getUid();
    StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(filePathAndName);
    storageReference2nd.putFile(uri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + taskSnapshot);
                    //Image has been uploaded to storage. Get its url and store it to Db
                    Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();

                    while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());

                    Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                    //Check if image is uploaded and its url received or not
                    if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                        //Image uploaded

                        //Update user's Db with the image
                        HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

                        results.put(profileOrCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());

                        databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess:");
                                        //url in Db of the user is added successfully
                                        LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image updeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e);
                                        //Some error occured
                                        LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occured...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                });

                    }

                    else {
                        //Error occured
                        LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "!Oops. Image upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e);
                    //Error occured so show the error msg to the user
                    LoadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

}

Below is the log message, please. This is my first time of asking a question on stackoverflow so if I couldn't follow any laid down rules, please pardon me

Logcat:

```
2019-06-21 18:02:25.528 13198-13198/com.example.skulmunsem D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-06-21 18:02:25.540 13198-13198/com.example.skulmunsem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.skulmunsem, PID: 13198
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65836, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/690/ORIGINAL/NONE/1059317505 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F690/ORIGINAL/NONE/1059317505} }} to activity {com.example.skulmunsem/com.example.skulmunsem.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume external not found
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4681)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1940)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7046)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Volume external not found
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1653)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1475)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1316)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1270)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:120)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:260)
        at com.example.skulmunsem.Fragment.ProfileFragment.uploadProfileCoverPhoto(ProfileFragment.java:534)
        at com.example.skulmunsem.Fragment.ProfileFragment.onActivityResult(ProfileFragment.java:512)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7966)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4632)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4681) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1940) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7046) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
2019-06-21 18:02:25.602 13198-13198/com.example.skulmunsem I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13198 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your stack trace of error messages. Also attempt to localize your error instead of posting your entire code.

Comment: @arjithn pls i am a novice when it comes to posting questions on this platform.kindly pardon me.

Comment: No Worries Kobby! Just sharing some reviews so that you can build upon these next time ;)